# Chart solo grafica cuando se da a inspeccionar código Angular

Tags: angular, cassandra, chart.js

En la clase component realizo todo el proceso de graficación; los datos viene desde backend en Spring.

Al traer los datos, no hay ningún problema, el problema radica al momento de graficar, cuando se inicia el servidor de angular aparece la grafica vacía y al momento de ver en inspección de código, aparece la gráfica. ¿Qué puede estar pasando?

```html
    
        ngOnInit(){
          this._dato.getGraficapm10()
          .subscribe(res => {
          this.ArrayDatos = [res];
          this.DatoEstandar();
          this.getFecha();
          //console.log(this.estandar);
          //console.log(this.fecha)
        });
    
    
        var speedData = {
          labels:this.fecha,
          datasets: [{
            label: "pm10",
            data: this.estandar
          }]
        };
    
        var chartOptions = {
          legend: {
            display: true,
            //position: 'top',
            labels: {
              boxWidth: 80,
              fontColor: 'black'
            }
          }
        };
    
        this.chart = new Chart("canvas", {
              type: 'line',
              data: speedData,
              options: chartOptions
            });
    };      
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A mi me ocurrió algo parecido cuando generaba un documento pdf en python, me generaba el gráfico y el pdf pero cuando abría el archivo no estaban juntos, lo que hice fue ir viendo los procesos que se iban realizando con solo print ... y encontré que me generaba el gráfico luego de generarme el informe. Quizás podrías ver en que momento te genera el gráfico o si es que demora mucho mas de lo estimado. Espero logres encontrar una buena solución

Comment: Tenias razon, estaba colocando la graficación donde no debia. Mil gracias por tu ayuda.